# Rxjs Async Interceptors - Keep on getting an error

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors, angular2-http

I need to add a token to the request in my interceptor. I keep on getting the error

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:73)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:68)
    at
```

Getting the token is an async operation

In AuthService.ts, I have

```js
  getToken2() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      return from(firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken());
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

My interceptor looks like below, but I keep on getting an error

```html
import {
  HttpInterceptor,HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { mergeMap, switchMap, flatMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../auth/auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const tokenObservable = this.authService.getToken2(); // if there is a user logged in
    if (tokenObservable) {
      tokenObservable.pipe(
        switchMap(token => {
          const copiedReq = req.clone({
            params: req.params.set("auth", token)
          });
          return next.handle(copiedReq);
        })
      );
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, it was a really silly mistake

I was missing the "return" in return this.authService.getToken2().pipe(

```
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("Attempt Intercept");
    if (req.method === "GET") {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    return this.authService.getToken2().pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        console.log("[AuthInterceptro]: token ", token);
        const copiedReq = req.clone({
          // headers: req.headers.append('', '')
          params: req.params.set("auth", token)
        });
        return next.handle(copiedReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```